# Why my return row[0] === userId.matches(userId); doesn't show nothing?

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script

i'm trying to create a tool for search products by name but i have some errors.
Concretly, I've a google sheet with two columns, one for the product name and the other one for the stock nº.
When i use the tool, only show results if the string searched is exactly the same than the string that includes the Google Sheet but i'd like to obtain all the results that contains the string introduced in the form.

Here you have the code for both files that i have: one for the form and the other for the js code.

```js
var myGoogleSheetURL =
  "HIDDENFORSECURITY";

var myGoogleSheetName = "HIDDENFORSECURITY";


function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('formulario');
  return template.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


function receiveForm(form) {
  var userId = form.userId;


  return searchData(userId);
}


function searchData(userId) {
  var sheet = getSpreadSheet(myGoogleSheetURL, myGoogleSheetName);

  var rowsResult = sheet
    .getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()
    .filter(function (row) {
      return row[0] === userId;
    });

  var firstRow = rowsResult[0];

  var user = {
    id: firstRow[0],
    email: firstRow[1],
    phone: firstRow[2],
  };


  var result = JSON.stringify(user);
  return result;
}


function getSpreadSheet(url, sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  return sheet;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>CJM STOCK SEARCH</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="HIDDENFORSECURITY">
    <base target="_top" />
    <style>
      :root {
        --primary-color: #4caf50;
      }
      body {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
      }
      input {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      input[type="text"] {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--primary-color);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      input[type="button"] {
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 10px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      input[type="button"]:disabled {
        background-color: #dadada;
      }
    </style>
    <title>HIDDENFORSECURITY</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="#">
      <input
        id="inputUserId"
        type="text"
        value=""
        name="userId"
        placeholder="PRODUCT NAME"
        onfocus="clearDiv()"
        onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"
      />
      <br />

      <input
        id="btnSend"
        type="button"
        onClick="formSubmit()"
        value="Search"
      />
    </form>

    <br>
    <div id="divResponse"></div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function formSubmit() {
      document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = "Searching...";

      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .receiveForm(document.forms[0]);


      disableInputs();
    }


    function onSuccess(response) {
  
      var user = JSON.parse(response);


      document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = user.email;

      enableInputs();
    }


    function onFailure() {
      // Pone mensaje en div
      document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = "Product not found";
      enableInputs();
    }

    function disableInputs() {
      document.getElementById("btnSend").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("inputUserId").disabled = true;
    }

    function enableInputs() {
      document.getElementById("btnSend").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("inputUserId").disabled = false;
    }

    function clearDiv() {
      document.getElementById("divResponse").innerHTML = "";
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me, please?
Sincerely i'm not an expert in JS, i've tried to search the solution in Google without success.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: `userId.matches(userId)` doesn't exist anywhere in your code.

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for the shorty reply. You have reason, in my last comment you have the last js code updated

Comment: I assume you're a Spanish speaker. If so, you can post your question and explain in Spanish at https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

As I can see in your code **row[0]** is the first value of your column. Keep in mind that the method [Range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns `Object[][] — A two-dimensional array of values`.

For that reason you probably are comparing the incorrect position of the cell.

Let's say this is your sheet:

```
+---+---------+------------+
|   |    A    |     B      |
|---|---------|------------|
| 1 | userID1 | someValue1 |
|---|---------|------------|
| 2 | userID2 | someValue2 |
|---|---------|------------|
| 3 | userID3 | someValue3 |
|---|---------|------------|
| 4 | userID4 | someValue4 |
+---+---------+------------+
```

In this case the value of **row[0]** will be userID1, userID2, userID3 and userID4 respectively. Therefore **userID** parameter is not a string or doesn't match any value in your range.

On the other hand if you have a sheet like the following:

```
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|   |      A     |      B     |      C     |      D     |
|---|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 1 | userID1    | userID2    | userID3    | userID4    |
|---|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 2 | someValue1 | someValue2 | someValue3 | someValue4 |
+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Here the value of **row[0]** will be userID1 and someValue1. That means you are comparing different values.

### References

- [Sheet.getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)